# Visual studio no me carga el form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

estoy trabajando en un proyecto winform. ayer todo esta funcionando sin problema, hoy enciendo la pc y a no logro ver los formularios en mi proyecto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que existen mucha info sobre este problema pero he buscado muchas soluciones y ninguna dan con mi error.

en este proyecto no puedo agregar otro formulario no me sale la opcion es como si el proyecto no fuera winfor, cuando si lo es.
-desintale el visual studio y es igual no funciono.
abri mi proyecto en blend y aqui me muestra los archivos del form [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si intento abrirlo en blend me arroja este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

clone mi proyecto y me conitunua el mismo error. agradeceria su  ayuda.

Comment: Seguramente borraste una propiedad o evento de algun componente en tu codeBehing de tu formulario y este no lo encuentra, entonces rompe. tenes que entrar al archivo de diseño de tu formulario, y eliminar la linea que te marca el error. Seguramente tu archivo se llama FrmSale.Designer.cs

Comment: error en el codigo no hay. ya di con la solucion. mi problema era al parecer con git. este me estaba borrando los archivos bin y otros mas y como estaba versionando ahi fue el lio, xd. lo que hice fue asegurarme de abriel el archivo.sln(de mi proyecto). y listo solucion para mi